# Counting 'False' values at the ends of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have table like this:

```
t = {False, False, False, 4.5, 6.789, 1.23, 0.98, False, False}
```

and I want to know how many False values I have at the beginning and at the end of the table.

I made:

```
size = Length[t]
t = Cases[t,Except[False]];
size2 = Length[t]
diff = size - size2
```

But this counts number of all `'False'` values inside the table. But I want to know how many is at the beginning and how many at the end (so i my example I have: 3 at the beginning and 2 at the end). How can I solve that?

Comment: If the list is all `False`, what you want, the length of the lsit or the numbers at the beginning and at the end separately?  (It's an edge-case in which the numbers of `False` and from the beginning and from the end are each equal to the length of the list.  Based on your example, I would assume in the case of all `False` you want the length and otherwise the sum of the runs.  But please clarify.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
before= LengthWhile[t, Not]

(* 3  *)

after = LengthWhile[Reverse[t], Not]

(* 2  *)
```

Comment: Very nice solution, I didn't get the idea about reversing the table. Thanks!

Comment: @Ziva In fact, reversing might not be optimal for long lists, you might be better off explicitly looping from the end then. For longer lists, however, mixing Boolean values with numbers may not be a good practice anyway.

Comment: @Ziva Thanks for the accept, but I'd wait for some more  answers before accepting one - this way you will encourage more solutions, including perhaps better ones.

Comment: +1 but IMHO it would be cleaner to eliminate `Function`: `LengthWhile[t, Not]`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Agreed. Edited.

Answer (score 10):

```
z = Split[t];
Map[Length, {First[z], Last[z]}]

(* {3, 2} *)
```

Comment: I get about a 40% reduction in computation time with `SplitBy` relative to `LengthWhile`.

Comment: I don't understand what you intend with `SplitBy[t, False]`.  I believe it is equivalent to `Split[t]` here.

Comment: Not `SplitBy`, `Split`. :-)  I would write: `Length /@ Split[t][[{1, -1}]]`, Also, note that this method will only work if one is certain that the list begins and ends with `False`; it cannot handle a "zero count" case.

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {False, False, False, 4.5, 6.789, 1.23, 0.98, False, False};
```

Using `SequenceCount` (new in 10.1)

```
SequenceCount[list, #] & /@ {{False, _}, {_, False}}
```

{3, 2}

Answer (score 2):

Using `SequenceCases`:

```
list = {False, False, False, 4.5, 6.789, 1.23, 0.98, False, False};

SequenceCases[list, s : {False ..} :> Length@s]

(*{3, 2}*)
```

Or using `SequenceSplit` and `Select`:

```
patt = {b : Longest[False ..]} :> {b};

Length /@ Select[SequenceSplit[list, patt], ! FreeQ[#, False] &]

(*{3, 2}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since @eldo keeps up the wonderful work and @E. Chan-López is following along I am providing an answer the question.

```
t = {False, False, False, 4.5, 6.789, 1.23, 0.98, False, False};
foreldo[list_] := Module[{adjacency, result},
   adjacency = 
    SparseArray[
      list /. x_ /; x > 0 -> 0 /. x_ /; x < 0 -> 0 /. 
       x_ /; x == 0 -> 0]["AdjacencyLists"];
   result = Length /@ Split[adjacency, #2 == # + 1 &];
   Print[
    "The number of consecutive False elements are --- from start to \
end"];
   Return[result];
   ];
```

Then, we have

```
foreldo[t]
```

returning

> [image: for eldo]

Answer (score 1):

Gives you the leading and trailing as a list:

```
LengthWhile[#, ! # &] & /@ {t, t // Reverse}
```

If you need to assign to symbols, e.g.,

```
{front, back}=LengthWhile[#, ! # &] & /@ {t, t // Reverse}
```

Edit: Just saw L.S.'s answer - same idea. As he notes, for huge lists reverse may not be the best way. I find the idiom `somelist[[-1;;1;;-1]]` a faster way, and depending on what you know about the structure of the data, other ways may be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rules-based solution as well so that we have one of those too:

```
t /. {f : False ..., Except[False] .., l : False ...} :> {Length[{f}], Length[{l}]}
```

Comment: I thought of this one too, but unfortunately it is *extremely* inefficient due to *Mathematica*'s failure to optimize pattern matching.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this and then noticed it is a variation on Anon's approach:

```
 # /. {___, x:Longest[False ...], __, y:Longest[False ...]} :> {Length[{x}], Length[{y}]} &
```

---

The same idea, with a named function:

```
f[list_] := Length[list /. {___, x : Longest[False ...], __} :> {x}]
```

Example:

```
 {f[t], f[Reverse[t]]}
```

> {3, 2}