# Command to take the first elements of a list that match a pattern

Tags: pattern-matching

I want to find the number of elements in a list in a row that match a certain pattern.

So for this list

```
{1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1}
```

It should return "4" because there are four 1's in a row and then other stuff. I don't care that there are more 1's later on. I just want to find the number of consecutive integers in a row, starting from the beginning of the list. Is there a simple way of doing this?

**Edit: I just realized my question was very poorly worded. I wanted to find the number of elements in a row starting from the beginning, regardless of what that element is.**

Comment: Related: [(40213)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40213/121)

Answer (score 5):

Regarding the updated description of your problem while `Split` is very clean it is not optimal unless the overall list is relatively short.  As an example consider this data:

```
SeedRandom[0];
a = RandomChoice[{"a", "b", "c"}, 1*^7];
```

It begins with:

```
{"c", "c", "b", "a", . . .}
```

The method from your answer takes significant time:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]  (* v10 package *)

Length[Split[a][[1]]] // AccurateTiming
```

> ```
> 1.303075
> ```

A method that does not process the entire list can be *much* faster:

```
LengthWhile[a, MatchQ @ First @ a] // AccurateTiming    (* v10 operator form *)
```

> ```
> 0.0000185558
> ```

For versions before 10 see kguler's **Update 2** code.

---

### Sidebar: timings of a pattern-based approach

Michael made the claim that his method is faster than `LengthWhile`.  In the particular test he used, where nearly the entire list consists of the same element it starts with, it is, but elsewhere it performs *extremely* poorly.  For example:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

f1[a_]    := LengthWhile[a, MatchQ @ First @ a]
f2[list_] := Replace[list, {y : Longest@Repeated[x_], ___} :> Length[{y}]]

g = (SeedRandom[0]; Clip @ RandomInteger[100, #]) &;   (* first zero at position 78 *)

BenchmarkPlot[{f1, f2}, g, 2^Range[20],
 "IncludeFits" -> True, TimeConstraint -> 30]
```

[image]

In this test the first differing element occurs at position 78 but the length of the list past that grows.  We see that `LengthWhile` correctly handles this in constant time whereas `Replace` explodes which should not happen if the pattern engine were well optimized.

Let us examine the pattern behavior by adding a `PatternTest` to `x_`:

```
SeedRandom[0]
list = Clip @ RandomInteger[100, 1000];

inc = (i++; True) &;

i = 0;
Replace[list, {y : Longest@Repeated[x_?inc], ___} :> Length[{y}]]
i
```

> ```
> 77
>
> 71148
> ```

Observe that despite there being only 77 ones at the start of the list, and the list in its entirety being only 1000 elements long, `Replace` performs over 71 *thousand* element tests.  This makes no sense but it is an old problem that I have [complained about before.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8522876)

Answer (score 3):

```
l = {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}
LengthWhile[l[[LengthWhile[l, # != 1 &] + 1 ;;]], # == 1 &]
(* 4 *)
```

Edit:

and this is dedicated to *that* special person:

```
k = LengthWhile;
l[[l~k~(# != 1 &) + 1 ;;]]~k~(# == 1 &)
(* 4 *)
```

Comment: And it's not even Christmas! :o)

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, a much better pattern (time complexity of order `n` instead of `n^2`), but still with a similar problem that Mr. Wizard pointed out.  It is perhaps interesting to wonder about the difference between these two patterns.

```
Replace[list, {x__, Except[First[list]], ___} :> Length[{x}]] /. y_List :> Length[y]
```

First version (time complexity of order `n^2`):

```
list = {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1};

Replace[list, {y : Longest@Repeated[x_], ___} :> Length[{y}]]
(* 4 *)
```

---

Mr. Wizard's comparison:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

f1[a_] := LengthWhile[a, MatchQ@First@a]
f2[list_] := Replace[list, {y : Longest@Repeated[x_], ___} :> Length[{y}]]
f3[list_] := Replace[list, {x__, Except[First[list]], ___} :> Length[{x}]] /. y_List :> Length[y]

g = (SeedRandom[0]; Clip @ RandomInteger[100, #]) &;  (*first zero at position 78*)

BenchmarkPlot[{f1, f2, f3}, g, 2^Range[20],
  "IncludeFits" -> True, TimeConstraint -> 30]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is interesting that `Longest` is super-fast when the list is shorter than `77` and consists of all ones.  It's too bad that a final `BlankNullSequence[]` does not short-circuit the pattern-matching.

Comment: Michael, I see that you added timings to your post.  In your example your method *is* faster but on other simple tests I found it to be *extremely* slow.  For example with `SeedRandom[0]; list = RandomInteger[1, 5*^4];` `Replace` takes 8.9 seconds where `LengthWhile` takes `0.000136` seconds.  I need to explore this further but I believe it is another exhibit of the poorly optimized nature of patterns in *Mathematica*.

Comment: Please see the addendum to my question.  I believe that your method would be just as fast as mine (if not faster) if the pattern engine worked properly but sadly it does not.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Oh gee, and here I thought I making a fair comparison by making it count high.  I had a nagging feeling that there was something wrong about patterns & speed, but I couldn't recall.  I just didn't do the right tests.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Since the community hasn't found the answer useful anyway, I'll probably delete.  I suppose it's list-manipulation fatigue.  Originally I just thought here's different a way.  When the original was ignored, I had to decide whether to respond to the change in the question. I did the timings to see how bad it was and was surprised.

Comment: You made me feel bad for not voting so +1.  Happy Halloween!  (And like I said this *should* be fast.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for the vote, but I didn't want you, or anyone, to feel bad.  I just figure that if no votes, then give a try at clarifying and pointing out the merits; if still no votes, probably delete, given I remember to check.  No hard feelings.  It's my interpretation of the SE model.  Happy Halloween, to you, too!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I found a better pattern but the problem with pattern matching remains.  Please see update, if you're interested.

Comment: I am very much interested!  A n^2 to n improvement is tremendous even if still not optimal.  Perhaps we need a Q&A about the complexity of different pattern forms?

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2:** Based on OP's latest clarification:

```
lfF = With[{x = First@#}, LengthWhile[#, # == x &]] &

lfF@{1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}
(* 4 *)

lfF@{0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}
(* 2 *)
```

or

```
lfF2 = Length@First@Split@# &;

lfF2@{1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}
(* 4 *)

lfF2@{0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}
(* 2*)
```

---

**Update:** Per comments on the original version, revised to account for lists that do not start with `1`:

```
list = {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1};

Length@First@Select[Split[list], First@# == 1 &, 1]
(* 4 *)

Length@First@Split[Flatten[Position[list, 1]], #2 - #1 <= 1 &]
(* 4 *)

First@Cases[list, {Except[1] ... , x : Longest[1 ..], ___} :> Length[{x}], {0}]
(* 4 *)
```

---

**Original post:**

```
list = {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1};

Length@First@Split[list]
(* 4 *)

LengthWhile[list, # == 1 &]
(* 4 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to thank everybody for their answers! I wanted to post an answer I saw in another question here on MSE but I can't seem to find it right now, but this was the solution that worked the simplest:

```
Length[Split[LIST][[1]]]
```

So Using `Split` partitions the list as I wanted, and then I can just take the first element of that partitioned list, and find the length of it. So here is a sample:

```
list = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}

Length[Split[list][[1]]]
```

gives

```
{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}

5
```

As desired. Again I didn't come up with this; I saw it somewhere else and I would like to link to it, but cannot find it.

Comment: This is clean and concise but be aware that it is quite inefficient on long lists as it splits the *entire* list even if you are only interested in a few elements at the beginning.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I just wanted something I could put into one line as minimally as possible so I could use it in a recursive function I was making.

Comment: It doesn't take much more code to "do it right" -- please see my just-posted answer.

Answer (score 1):

... If your list

```
list={1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1};
```

was a String :

```
mystring = (StringJoin @@ ToString /@ list)
(* 1111000111 *)
```

you could also do :

```
StringCases[mystring, s : (StartOfString ~~ (x_) ..) :> StringLength@s][[1]]
(* 4 *)
```

or

```
StringPosition[mystring, (StartOfString ~~ (x_) ..)][[1, -1]]
(* 4 *)
```

It is also fast because it just searchs the "start of the string".

**Edit: Benchmarking**

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];
f1s[st_] := StringCases[st, s : (StartOfString ~~ (x_) ..) :> StringLength@s][[1]];
f2s[st_] := StringPosition[st, (StartOfString ~~ (x_) ..)][[1, -1]];
gs = (SeedRandom[0]; StringJoin @@ ToString /@ Clip@RandomInteger[100, #]) &;
```

then

```
BenchmarkPlot[{f1s, f2s}, gs, 2^Range[15], "IncludeFits" -> True, TimeConstraint -> 30]
```

gives a log(n) behaviour

[image]

whereas for longer lists ...

```
BenchmarkPlot[{f1s, f2s}, gs, 2^Range[20], "IncludeFits" -> True, TimeConstraint -> 30]
```

[image]

For relative time comparison here is what I get for the benchmarking of the other posts :

[image]

**Update : for integers > 9**

In the original post, I did not take into account (as remarked in the comment) that the list could contain integers >9 ... (however all the benchmarking and examples in the proposed answers do not treat this case).

Anyway, let's take the proposed list in the comment :

```
list = {1, 1, 111, 1111, 11111, 2, 3};
```

and transform it into a "useful" string

```
mystring = " " <> StringDrop[ToString@list, 1]
(* 1, 1, 111, 1111, 11111, 2, 3}*)

(*you could also test directly :*)
(*mystring="1,1,111,1111,11111,2,3"*)
```

then

```
StringCases[mystring, a : (StartOfString ~~ Shortest[(x__) ~~ ","] ..) :> 
StringLength@a/(StringLength@x + 1)][[1]]
(*2*)
```

does the job and should be fast because it focuses on the start of the string.

Of course, the question was not about strings, but I thought it was interesting to extend and test ;)

Comment: What if my list is `{1, 1, 111, 1111, 11111, 2, 3}`?

Comment: @rm-rf ? What do you mean ? What result would you expect here ?

Comment: He is pointing out the fact that you cannot simply concatenate numbers while preserving their individual identity.  If you were to concatenate `{1, 1, 111, 1111, 11111, 2, 3}` you would get a result of fourteen when the actual result should be two.

Comment: @rm-rf please see my update

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Please, see my update and benchmarking.